# Do people care about "Six Sigma" for probability distributions that are not Normal?

Tags: probability, statistics

**Background**

At work there is a "Six Sigma" team that focuses on reducing quality defects. They're named that way because six sigma covers 99.7% around the mean (for a normal distribution).

So if a manufacturing process covers six sigma of deviations when the randomness is normally distributed then the process is perhaps good.

**Question 1**

Is it a thing to talk about how many sigmas are needed to "cover" other distributions? For example, the Gamma or the Poisson?

**Question 2**

Is the following correct?

- $X$ is a continuous Uniform RV from $(0,1)$ which means the variance is $1/12$ and the SD is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}$
- Therefore "six sigma" covers $6\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}} \approx 1.73$ or all observations

**Question 3**

I'm trying to calculate how many sigmas to cover the Exponential for any $\lambda$.

Is the following correct?

- This is tough for me to figure out because unlike the binomial and normal, the exponential is not symmetrical around the mean
- I'm going to cop out and calculate how many sigmas cover the pdf starting from zero instead of around the mean...
- The variance of an exponential is $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ so sigma is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and I want to know how many multiples $m$ of sigma cover 99.7%

$$P(X \le \frac{m}{\lambda}) = 0.997$$

$$1 - e^{-\lambda \frac{m}{\lambda}} = 0.997$$

$$1- e^{-m} = 0.997$$

$$ e^{-m} = 0.003$$

$$ m = -ln(0.003)$$

Therefore, regardless of lambda, to cover 99.7% of the pdf you need 5.8 sigmas (which is close to six sigmas).

---

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: The third paragraph of the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) looks relevant.

Comment: A more robust measure of the spread is the inter-quartile difference (IQD); it works for many distributions that standard deviation is unsuitable for, and $\pm 3$ IQD is a [Tukey criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Tukey%27s_fences) for outlier.

Comment: Incidentally, I remember the margins on $1$, $2$, and $3$ standard deviations as one part in $\pi$, $7\pi$, and $16e^\pi$. :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. When I asked the question I wasn't aware of Chebyshev's inequality. I will also look into IQD.

Comment: @leonbloy This is really interesting: "even for non-normally distributed variables, at least 88.8% of cases should fall within properly calculated three-sigma intervals" // I would think that you could create a very bimodal distribution to break this rule but I guess not. I am still in the middle of my beginning probability book so I will get to the Chebyshev Inequality eventually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Empirical Rule" states that if $X$ has a 'mound-shaped` distribution,
then $P(\mu - \sigma < X \le \mu + \sigma) \approx .68,\,$
$P(\mu - 2\sigma < X \le \mu + 2\sigma) \approx .95,\,$ and
$P(\mu - 3\sigma < X \le \mu + 3\sigma) \approx 1.$ These
probabilities are nearly correct for a normal distribution.

[Of course Chebyshev's Inequality puts bounds on the second and
third probabilities, but the bounds are not always useful in
applications. Because Chebyshev's Inequality is a *Theorem* that
applies to very many different distributions, it does not give
'tight' bounds for most distributions.]

Moreover,
similar statements for *proportions* of observations
in a normal sample, in terms of *sample* means and standard deviations,
are often close enough to correct to be useful.

If the PDF or a distribution or histogram of a sample is 'mound-shaped' in the sense that it is very nearly normal, it is realistic to expect the
approximations to be good approximations. As you have noticed, there
some distributions that are not 'mound shaped' for which some of the
probabilities happen to match reality. The Empirical Rule is not
meant as a theorem, but as the word *empirical* suggests, it is often
useful in practice.

(1) How much attention is paid to the Empirical Rule (ER) in general, and
to the third part of it in particular, depends on circumstances. Some
elementary texts mention it in passing (sometimes with a contrived
sample), and others return to it in a thematic way whenever nearly
normal distributions are mentioned. It is important to recognize that
a normal *sample* (especially a small one) may not behave in the same
way as the normal distribution from which it taken.

[As a possible example of excessive emphasis: In my opinion, the so-called 'six-sigma' quality management movement places
unwarranted attention on the last of the the three statements of the ER, 
emphasizing cases in which the "effective support" of a distribution
spans an interval that is about six standard deviations long, while placing
too little attention on situations in which the actual support is
an 'interval' of infinite length.]

(2) A uniform distribution is in no sense 'mound shaped', so it is not
surprising that the third part of the ER does not apply--even approximately.
As you say, if $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ then $P(1/4 < X \le 3/4) = 1/2,$
which is far from 1.

(3) If $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(rate = 1/4),$ then $\mu = \sigma = 4,$ and
$$P(\mu - 3\sigma < X \le \mu + 3\sigma) = P(-8 < X \le 16) = P(X \le 16) = 0.9817.$$ Also, $P(X \le 6\sigma =24) = 0.9975.$ So there happen to be two senses in
which a 'six-sigma' rule works for this exponential distribution. [It may be
cheating to invoke the ER here, because an exponential is certainly not
'mound shaped'.]

```
pexp(16, 1/4)
## 0.9816844
pexp(24, 1/4)
## 0.9975212
```

Finally, let's explore briefly how well the ER works when applied to
sample of size $n = 50$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15).$
The following simulation looks at 100,000 such samples. For each sample we find the proportion `ER1` of the 50 observations falling within the
interval $(\bar X - S, \bar X + S).$ And similarly for the second and
third parts of the ER. It turns out that about 68% of the samples
satisfy the first part of the ER, about 95% satisfy the second part,
and over 99% satisfy the third part. Many other interpretations and
simulations might have been chosen, but this one simulation shows that
the ER works about as advertised for samples from a normal population.

```
set.seed(308)
m = 10^5;  n = 50
ER1 = ER2 = ER3 = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
   x = rnorm(n, 100, 15);  a=mean(x);  s=sd(x)
   ER1[i] = mean(x > a-s & x < a+s)
   ER2[i] = mean(x > a-2*s & x < a+2*s)
   ER3[i] = mean(x > a-3*s & x < a+3*s) }
mean(ER1); mean(ER2); mean(ER3)
## 0.6825468
## 0.9578796
## 0.9983232
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I talked to the Six Sigma people at work but none of them are really into statistics. Which might be dangerous because they basically assume everything is normally distributed. Perhaps this may be acceptable because of the CLT which I haven't gotten to yet in my probability studies. Thanks for your answers to my other questions since it seems the Empirical rule is focused on the normal and not other non mound distributions like the uniform and exponential. I will meditate on your answer to fully digest it.

Comment: If key questions remain after meditation, please leave a note and maybe someone can say something helpful.

Comment: One question -- what language is that where you did the simulation verifying the ER? Is it R perhaps? I want to run it myself for training and also to test different values for mu and sigma. I'm thinking because you can transform any Normal to the Unit Normal, then the ER should hold always even if you have crazy stuff like mu = 100 and sigma = 1000000... is this intuition correct?

Comment: R statistical software. // **Yes,** my mean 100 and SD 15 are arbitrary. It is important that the sample size not be too small (what is 68% of n=7?) and that data not be rounded too much, especially if the SD is small.

Comment: Ah I see, so mean and SD of the true underlying normal distribution can be arbitrary, but the sample size is important. At this point I'm trying to learn beginner probability concepts so I haven't gotten into sample sizes yet, though I can see how it matters. I will play around with R.

Comment: If you use `set.seed(308)` you will get _exactly_ the same results I did when running the program. If you omit that statement, R will pick its own seed (from msec in the system clock) for the random generation of samples. With $m = 10^5$ iterations (samples of 50) you should not get substantially different answers no matter what seed is used.